# Can't install Previous version of Datastax DSE

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

trying to:

```
apt-get install 'dse-full=4.6.5-1'
```

and getting:

```
failed: [dsenode01] => {"failed": true}
stderr: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

stdout: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dse-full : Depends: dse (= 4.6.5-1) but 4.7.0-1 is to be installed
            Depends: dse-hive (= 4.6.5-1) but 4.7.0-1 is to be installed
            Depends: dse-pig (= 4.6.5-1) but 4.7.0-1 is to be installed
            Depends: dse-demos (= 4.6.5-1) but 4.7.0-1 is to be installed
            Depends: dse-libsolr (= 4.6.5-1) but 4.7.0-1 is to be installed
            Depends: dse-libtomcat (= 4.6.5-1) but 4.7.0-1 is to be installed
            Depends: dse-libsqoop (= 4.6.5-1) but 4.7.0-1 is to be installed
            Depends: dse-liblog4j (= 4.6.5-1) but 4.7.0-1 is to be installed
            Depends: dse-libmahout (= 4.6.5-1) but 4.7.0-1 is to be installed
            Depends: dse-libspark (= 4.6.5-1) but 4.7.0-1 is to be installed

msg: 'apt-get install 'dse-full=4.6.5-1' ' failed: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

$ sudo apt-get update $ sudo apt-get install dse-full=version-1 dse=version-1 dse-hive=version-1 dse-pig=version-1 dse-demos=version-1 dse-libsolr=version-1 dse-libtomcat=version-1 dse-libsqoop=version-1 dse-liblog4j=version-1 dse-libmahout=version-1 dse-libhadoop-native=version-1 dse-libcassandra=version-1 dse-libhive=version-1 dse-libpig=version-1 dse-libhadoop=version-1

Or thanks to @Ian Evans, use aptitude:

`sudo aptitude install dse-full=4.6.5-1`

http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/install/installDEBdse.html

Comment: Thanks! I've use ansible to setup C*. It was ok in May and after two months it doesn't work. I didn't put that commands into Ansible before. Surprised a little... P.S. Last updated: 12 June 2015 omg... thanks... you saved my day.

Comment: Must be since 4.7 dropped

Comment: Using aptitude makes this a lot easier.
sudo aptitude install dse-full=4.6.5-1

Then choose the install plan that installs the 4.6.5 versions of all the dependencies.